# RL circuit paradox

Tags: inductor, inductance, inductive

I can't understand why current flow through an inductor in RL circuit if this inductor induces EMF to block it? Well, the current at t=0 is 0 but how the current increases seems to be paradoxal :(
Thanks :)  [image]

Comment: SHOW THE CIRCUIT you are asking about.  Otherwise, I don't see how you can *not* think current can flow thru a inductor.  You seem to have a misconception that inductors "block" current, which isn't true.  Again, show the circuit, what voltages you are applying over time, and we can talk about what the currents are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inductors don't block current, they tend to resist *changes* in current.

The induced voltage is \$v = L \frac{di}{dt}\$. This induced voltage opposes the current flow.

[image]

As you can see, the inductor resists the sharp change in current that would occur with a short instead of the inductor. Athough it resists this change, it does not completely prevent it. Over time, the current approaches what would be the case with a short instead of an inductor.

Comment: But the inductor prevent it at t=0, so how can the current flow after ?

Comment: @user36767: It is implicit that the voltage source has been turned on at t=0, so di/dt is potentially very high at t=0. However, if i remained 0 at t>0, di/dt would be 0 (and any induced V 0). So i does not remain 0.

Comment: great demonstration ;) but can I explain it saying the EMF (t=0) induced don't last more than dt, hence it allows current rising and inducing an EMF2 < EMF ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to understand this if you don't get hung up about back EMF produced by a inductor and instead think of the current thru a inductor rising proportionally with the voltage applied to it.  You can mathematically derive the back EMF from this, so it's saying the same thing I think that you are thinking, but this will be easier to conceptualize.

To characterize a inductor in concrete terms: A/s = V/H, or the Amps per second rise in the current thru the inductor is the Volts applied to it divided by its inductance in Henries.  For example, if you connected a 1 Volt power supply to a 2 Henrie inductor, then the current would slowly build at 1/2 Amp per second.  It's fine to think of this as the *definition* of a inductor, since other definitions you might hear can all be derived from this one (and vice versa).  I picked this way of looking at it, again, because I think it is more intuitive to the beginner.

Now let's look at your circuit.  E is the power supply and L is the inductor, and you have a additional wrinkle with R in series.  Let's again say for sake of example that E is 1 Volt and L is 2 Henries.  When you first apply power (E goes from having been 0 for a long time to 1 V), the current is 0.  That means the voltage accross the resistor is 0 (see Ohm's law), and the full voltage of E is applied to the inductor.  This mean that immediately after turning on E, the current will start rising by 1/2 A per second.

Now think about what happen a little time later.  After 1 second the current would be 1/2 A (500 mA).  However, that 500 mA will cause a voltage drop accross R, so the inductor is no longer driven by the full 1 V, but something less.  This means the current rises more slowly than the 500 mA/s it did initially.  Let's say that R is 1 Ω.  At 500 mA it drops 500 mV (1/2 V), so when 500 mA is flowing, there is only 500 mV left accross the inductor and the current will rise *at that specific point in time* at a rate of 250 mA/s.  In fact, the current rise started slowing down just as soon as a little current started flowing.  That caused a little voltage drop accross the resistor, which decreased the voltage accross the inductor a little bit, which slowed the current rise a little bit.  Another little while later, more current has built up, which causes more voltage on R, which causes less voltage on L, which makes the current rise even more slowly.

It might sound like this is a insolvable chicken versus egg problem, but you can write everything I said in words above as a mathematical *differential equation*, which in this case has a rather straight forward and well known solution.  The current ends up rising according to a *exponential function* that approaches simply E/R.  Note that when the current reaches E/R, all the voltage is accross the resistor, so none is left accross the inductor, so the current can't go up anymore.  In theory the current can only get ever closer to E/R, but never actually get there.  In practise, there is some level of good enough or the difference is below your ability to measure it, so either way you don't care anymore.

It turns out that the shape of these exponential functions are all the same and differ only in how long they take.  A single parameter, called the *time constant*, is used to characterize each specific exponential.  The time constant of a resistor and inductor circuit like you show is R/L.  It so happens that when R is in Ohms and L in Henries, that R/L comes out in units of seconds.  In our example T, the time constant, is 1Ω/2H = 500 ms.  This means each 500 ms (1/2 second), the current gets e times closer to its final value.  The mathematical constant e is 2.72 (rounded to three digits), so after half a second, the current gets 2.72 times closer to its final value of 1 A after 1/2 second, which means it will be 632 mA.

This is exactly the same as a *half life*, just that for various mathematical reasons a factor of e is actually more convenient that the more human-friendly factor of 2.  It so happens that the half life is .699 (rounded to 3 significant digits) e-based time constants.  Since our time constant was 500 ms, the half life is therefore 350 ms.  That means each 350 ms, the current goes half way from what it was to the steady state value.  Since the steady state value is 1 A, after 350 ms it will be 1/2 A, 3/4 A after 699 ms, 7/8 A after 1.048 seconds, etc.

Comment: actually the problem is between t=0 and t=0+ : A steady current doesn't generate back EMF. At the first instant, if the back EMF is 1V, it stops all current. But if all current stops, then there is no change in current, and so nothing sustains the back EMF. But any collapse in the back EMF allows a trickle of current which props up the EMF again. This situation, is it explained only by mathematical calculus?

Comment: @user: Back EMF doesn't stop current.  The rise in current is proportional to the *applied* voltage, regardless of how much back EMF the inductor is making.  I explained it in terms of voltage causes rise of current, but you can think of it exactly the opposite as rise of current causes voltage.  The two are linked, and which one is the cause of the other is just a way of thinking about it.  One view may  make more sense for any particular circuit.  If you put a fixed voltage on a inductor the current will rise.  If you force a rising current then the voltage will be set.  Same thing.